# How to insert delimitter on key up after 7 letters/alphabet/numbers and new letters in new line- Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

How to put comma after 7 letters on keyup event,Below is my code where I am able to get comma after 7 letters but when it goes to next line it doesn't work properly.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID ="txtbillno" runat="server" onkeyup="InsertComma();" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>


 function InsertComma() {
      var txtObj = document.getElementById('<%=txtbillno.ClientID %>');
      var txtVal = replaceAll(txtObj.value, ',', '');
      if (txtObj.value != "") {
           var newVal = "";
           for (var i = 0; i < txtVal.length; i++) {
                newVal = newVal + txtVal.substring(i, i + 1);

                if ((i + 1) % 7 == 0 && i != 0) {
                    newVal = newVal + "," + "\n";
                }
           }
            txtObj.value = newVal;
      }

 }

 function replaceAll(txt, replace, with_this) {
      return txt.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'), with_this);
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean like this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a6139do/2/)? Let me know and if that's right I'll post a complete answer explaining the solution

Comment: Yes , same as it is Fiddle..@IanA

Answer (score 0):

In your `InsertComma` function you were correctly removing the commas:

```
var txtVal = replaceAll(txtObj.value, ',', '');
```

but `txtVal` still contains the new line characters (\n), so I added a line to remove those too:

```
txtVal = replaceAll(txtVal, '\n', '');
```

The complete `InsertComma` method is:

```
function InsertComma() {
  var txtObj = document.getElementById('txtbillno');
  // Remove commas
  var txtVal = replaceAll(txtObj.value, ',', '');
  // Remove new line characters
  txtVal = replaceAll(txtVal, '\n', '');
  if (txtObj.value != "") {
       var newVal = "";
       // Append commas
       for (var i = 0; i < txtVal.length; i++) {
            newVal = newVal + txtVal.substring(i, i + 1);

            if ((i + 1) % 7 == 0 && i != 0) {
                newVal = newVal + "," + "\n";
            }
       }
        txtObj.value = newVal;
  }

 }
```

and a working example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2a6139do/2/)